# How to reference entity with it's self referenced dependencies in EF CodeFirst database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say I have product and category entities:

```
public class DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}    

public class Product : DatabaseEntity {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ... 
    public Category PrimaryCategory {get;set;}
}

public class Category : DatabaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Category is self referenced - each category has optional one parent and N children. Category entity configuration looks like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
         .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
         .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

When I try to get category using my repository method:

```
public Category GetCategory(int id)
{
    if (id == default (int)) return null;

    // Initialize relations
    var categories = _repository.AllIncluding<Category>(c => c.Parent, c => c.Categories).ToList();

    return categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
}
```

I get full category hierarchy with all children and parents (parent of parent of parent etc ...). But how can I get this full hierarchy when I try to get product from database?

```
public Product GetProduct(string linkName)
{
      var products = _repository.AllIncluding<Product>(
            ...    
            p => p.Properties,                
            p => p.Images,
            ...
            p => p.PrimaryCategory,
            p => p.PrimaryCategory.Parent
            ...
      ).ToList();

      var product = products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.LinkName.Equals(linkName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
      return product;
}
```

But in this case I get only category and it's one parent. Grand parent is null but actually it is not. I could do:

```
p => p.PrimaryCategory,
p => p.PrimaryCategory.Parent,
p => p.PrimaryCategory.Parent.Parent,
p => p.PrimaryCategory.Parent.Parent.Parent ...
```

But it is just silly )))

I tried to configure product entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
          .HasOptional(p => p.PrimaryCategory)
          .WithMany()
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

... or download and attach categories manually:

```
var products = _repository.AllIncluding<Product>(
         ...    
         p => p.Properties,                
         p => p.Images,               
         ...
         p => p.PrimaryCategory 
         ...
).ToList();

var product = products.SingleOrDefault(...);
product.PrimaryCategory = GetCategory(product.PrimaryCategory.Id);
```

... but, I think, this is super wrong. I, obviously, need some correct entity configuration.

Here is `AllIncluding` implementation - common generic db repository:

```
public IQueryable<TObject> AllIncluding<TObject>(params Expression<Func<TObject, object>>[] includeProperties) where TObject : DatabaseEntity
{
       IQueryable<TObject> query = _database.Set<TObject>();
       return includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
}
```

How can I configure entities to get full `PrimaryCategory` hierarchy?

Comment: It's not about configuration, but is about how would you fetch the data. Where is your implementations?

Comment: I used to write an extension method to recursively get all parents manually, but there should be better solution.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry, I added some edits

Comment: Well, you probably consider it yet, but what about lazy loading by puting a virtual on your properties ?

Comment: @tschmit007, it was the first thing I tried...

Comment: Have you tried configuring the product and explicitly mapping the keys in that configuration?